# Is there a way to trigger mousedown with jquery and hold it for x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I just couldn't find any tips on that, any one may know a way of doing that ?

EDIT: the goal is to trigger a ripple effect on a button https://lv-ripple.antoniodalsie.com, to using `$('#button').trigger('mousedown')` works but the animation is way too short, it uses timestamps given in events object i think.

Comment: Have you at least tried anything? Also some code to explain why you want to do this in the first place may help as there maybe a better and even simpler way

Comment: What do you mean by hold it for x seconds?

Comment: Think about it, there's no way to measure the length of a mousedown event, other than listening for the mouseup event ...

Comment: Just do `$(element).trigger('mousedown')` and then after a given time, do `$(element).trigger('mouseup')` and you should have simulated a mouse button being held down for a given time.

Comment: Why are there three answers explaining how to bind an event and measuring the time rather than how to **trigger** it _with a specified time_, which is what this question is actually asking?

Comment: Yes i did that, and i noticed that a mouseup had to be set automatically somehow, i tested on https://lv-ripple.antoniodalsie.com/, because i want to trigger a ripple effect manually, you can test on a button and see how fast it is. I think the lib is using timestamps passed on the events

Comment: Did you try just triggering a `click`? I'm not sure I get this.

Answer (score -3):

You can do that following (refer to http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/):

```
   var interval;
    $(button).addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {

        },500); 
    });
    $(button).addEventListener('mouseup',function(e) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
    $(button).addEventListener('mouseout',function(e) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
```

Comment: What do event listeners have anything to do with the question? The question is about **triggering** events with certain time intervals, not *listening* to events.